# Retry SQL UPDATE query after waiting x seconds

Tags: sql, scala, prepared-statement, apache-flink, flink-streaming

I am using a [RichSinkFunction](https://ci.apache.org/projects/flink/flink-docs-release-1.2/api/java/org/apache/flink/streaming/api/functions/sink/RichSinkFunction.html) to execute a SQL UPDATE query on an existing record.
This function assumes that a record already exists on the DB. However, in certain scenarios the existing record is late.

To overcome the issue of record lateness, I have added a `Thread.sleep()` to make the function wait and retry the DB update.

Sample code provided below for reference.

```
class RichSinkFact extends RichSinkFunction[FulfillmentUsagesOutput]{

private def updateFactUpcoming(
    r: FulfillmentUsagesOutput,
    schemaName: String
  ): Unit = {

    var updateStmt: PreparedStatement = null
    val sqlStatement =
      s"""
         |UPDATE $schemaName.$factUpcomingTableName
         |SET unit_id = ?
         |WHERE pledge_id = ?
         |;
         |
      """.stripMargin

    try {
      updateStmt = connection.prepareStatement(sqlStatement)
      updateStmt.setLong(1, r.unit_id)
      updateStmt.setString(2, r.pledge_id)
      val rows = updateStmt.executeUpdate()

      if(rows == 0) {
        logger.warn(s"Retrying update for ${r}")
        //retry update
        Thread.sleep(retrySleepTime)
        val rows = updateStmt.executeUpdate()
        if(rows == 0){
          //raise error
          logger.error(s"Unable to update row: ${r}")
        }
      }

    } finally {
      if (updateStmt != null) {
        updateStmt.close()
      }
    }
  }
}
```

**Question** : Since Flink already implements other timers and uses internal time processing functions, is this the right way of retrying a DB update?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to David for the original idea behind this approach.
[Sink.ProcessingTimeService](https://ci.apache.org/projects/flink/flink-docs-stable/api/java/org/apache/flink/api/connector/sink/Sink.ProcessingTimeService.html) is only present from Flink 1.12 onwards. So, for anyone on a previous version of Flink looking to implement a similar solution, [ProcessingTimeCallback](https://ci.apache.org/projects/flink/flink-docs-release-1.11/api/java/org/apache/flink/streaming/runtime/tasks/ProcessingTimeCallback.html) can be used to implement timers in a Sink application.

I have included a sample approach here
https://gist.github.com/soumoks/f73694c64169c8b3494ba1842fa61f1b

Answer (score 1):

As you suspected, sleeping in a Flink user function can cause problems, and should be avoided. In this case there is a better solution: take a look at [Sink.ProcessingTimeService](https://ci.apache.org/projects/flink/flink-docs-stable/api/java/org/apache/flink/api/connector/sink/Sink.ProcessingTimeService.html). This will let you register timers that will call a callback you register when they fire.

Comment: Thanks David. It looks like this interface is only present in Flink 1.12 onwards. We are currently on Flink 1.9 and the closest I found is another class.

https://ci.apache.org/projects/flink/flink-docs-release-1.9/api/java/org/apache/flink/streaming/runtime/tasks/ProcessingTimeService.html

However, since I am already extending `RichSinkFunction`, I would not be able to extend another class. Let me know if there is a similar implementation in Flink 1.9